# ng An unhandled exception occurred: Project does not exist

Tags: ionic-framework

D:\newOne\New folder\Admin_panel>ionic serve

> ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
> [ng] An unhandled exception occurred: Project does not exist.
> [ng] See "C:\Users\RAVIYA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-Iozhse\angular-errors.log" for further details.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 127).

```
    The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

Comment: Need more details .. cant help it with these details

Comment: This is how you should start an Ionic Project : ```ionic start myApp blank```